# How To Pass Control As A Variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables

This is one of those problems which seems like it should have a simple solution but I can't work out what it is!

How can I pass a control from one sub to another if the first sub doesn't actually call the second?  For example, where btnChangeText is in a panel that has a ModalPopupExtender called mpExample, and therefore isn't usually visible:

```
Protected Sub btnChangeText_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeText.Click

<SpecifiedTextBox>.Text = "Hello"

End Sub
```

And then on the main page, visible at all times, is a button associated with each textbox.  In this example, it's textbox15:

```
Protected Sub btnChangeTextBox15_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeTextBox15.Click

<Set TextBox15 as variable>
mpExample.Show()

End Sub
```

I know it's a silly example - believe me when I say that the real application I want to make of this actually makes sense!  But the point is that I want to somehow store the name of the control to be updated by the first sub when the second sub is run.

If I was calling the first sub from the second it'd be easy, I'd just pass it as an argument, but I'm not.  The first sub is called from a button click and is an independent action from the running of the second sub.

I don't seem to be able to use a session variable (my first thought) because I can't find any way to store the control name as a string and then convert it back to an actual control when the first sub runs.  That'd be the easiest answer if somebody could tell me how to do it.

Comment: This question goes beyond technical questions about programming and ventures into architectural design. This question probably fits better on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @jadarnel27 - When you store TextBoxes in Session, beware that pages (and their controls) are recreated for every request, so the reference is not valid in the next request.

Comment: @HansKesting Sorry, I was deleting my comment when you posted yours.  That's a very good point.  Perhaps the second approach in my answer is a better way of going about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to store the control's ID as a string in a Session variable, and then use the `FindControl` method to grab the control in your 2nd Click event.

```
Protected Sub btnChangeTextBox15_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeTextBox15.Click
    Session("currentTextBox") = TextBox15.ID
    mpExample.Show()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnChangeText_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeText.Click
    Dim currentTextBox As TextBox
    currentTextBox = CType(Page.FindControl(Session("currentTextBox")),TextBox)
    currentTextBox.Text = "Hello"
End Sub
```

Note that if your TextBox15 control is inside some kind of container (a Panel or something), you'll need to use that container's `FindControl` method, rather than `Page.FindControl`.

---

Another approach is to store the `TextBox` itself in a Session variable, and then pull that out to set the text in your other method.  Note that this only works if the methods are both called in the same request (which doesn't sound like it would work for your use-case).  Here's what that would look like:

```
Protected Sub btnChangeTextBox15_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeTextBox15.Click
    Session("currentTextBox") = TextBox15
    mpExample.Show()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnChangeText_Click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeText.Click
    Dim currentTextBox As TextBox
    currentTextBox = CType(Session("currentTextBox"), TextBox)
    currentTextBox.Text = "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, full disclosure time!  I didn't realise you could store controls in session variables, or, indeed, anything except strings.  That's really useful to know.

However, what I'm actually trying to do is store a FormView in the session variable, and then call the DataBind method with my button, and that's not working using this method. Is it possible that a FormView is too big to store in a session variable?

Comment: Not to worry.  Your second method, storing the control ID rather than the control itself, works just fine.  I just thought that storing the whole control was more elegant than using the FindControl method.  Also, I didn't need to use CType, I just used `currentTextBox = Page.FindControl(Session("currentTextBox"))` (or equivalent).

Comment: @PhilipStratford Great! Glad that worked. Yeah, storing the whole control will only work if both methods are called during the same postback (because the page is recreated during each postback - see Hans comment on your question).  Basically, if you store the control on the first postback, and try to do something with it on the next, your referring to a control that is no longer on the page (it's out of date).

Comment: @PhilipStratford PS: I was also pretty excited when I discovered you could put any object into Session variables.  Be careful not to abuse it, though - each thing you store in there is more RAM your app is using.